# NodeJS / Express Why am I getting "Cannot Read Property 'then' of Undefined"?

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I apologize in advance because I have seen other questions on this very topic, but I do not understand what I am doing wrong and how to fix it. Please have a look at my code:

```
function getSum(productID) {
  Rating.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$productID",
          total: {
            $sum: "$rating"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        //console.log("product-sum: " + req.body.productID)
        const count = result.find(item => item._id === productID.productID);
        console.log("getSum count: ", count.total);
        return count.total;
      }
    }
  );
}

router.route('/compute-rating').post((req, res) => {
  console.log("compute Rating: ", req.body.data);
  var productID = req.body.data;
  var sum = getSum(productID).then( //getting the error here

    res.json({ sum })
  );
});
```

getSum() returns a valid number from count.total.

Once I get the sum, I plan to chain another .then onto the existing then and call another function with the productID, but I need to use the sum later in the computer-rating route.

In the code, I have a comment that shows where the error,  "Cannot Read Property 'then' of Undefined", is occurring. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Edit:
I wanted to show my final solution so others could benefit from my experience. Hopefully I did not create any major Javascript violations in my code. I ended up using Promise.all because I had to perform a calculation based on 2 returned values.

```
function getSum(productID) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const result = await Rating.aggregate( //sum of a column in MongoDB
      [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$productID",
            total: {
              $sum: "$rating"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    );
    
    try {
      var sum = result.find(item => item._id === productID.productID);

      if (sum !== undefined) {
        resolve(sum);
        console.log("getSum sum: ", sum);
      }
      else {
        reject("invalid product id");
      }

    }
    catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}

function getCount(productID) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    
    var result = await Rating.countDocuments(productID)
      .then(count => {
        console.log("getCount count:", result);
        var documentCount = { count: count }
        resolve(documentCount);
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}

router.route('/compute-rating').post((req, res) => {
  console.log("compute Rating: ", req.body.data);
  var productID = req.body.data;

  Promise.all([getSum(productID), getCount(productID)])
    .then(results => {
      console.log("compute rating results: ", results);

      if (results[1].count > 0) {

        res.status(200).json({ rating: results[0].total / results[1].count });
      }
      else {
        res.status(200).json({ rating: 0 });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err });
    })

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getSum` doesn't return anything. You are returning only from the callback function, not the `getSum` function.
You should make it `async`.

And also you are doing `res.send` in that function, while not having access to `res` object.

For example you can do it like this:

```
async function getSum(productID) {
  const result = await Rating.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$productID",
          total: {
            $sum: "$rating"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  );
  const count = result.find(item => item._id === productID.productID);
  console.log("getSum count: ", count.total);
  return count.total;
}

router.route('/compute-rating').post((req, res) => {
  console.log("compute Rating: ", req.body.data);
  var productID = req.body.data;
  
  // EDIT: This should work
  getSum(productID).then(sum => {
    res.json({ sum })
  });
});
```

Comment: making it async is a good start, but you didn't use `await`, meaning that calling `then` will be immediate, not waiting for the aggregate to finish, yet again you can't `await` a function that doesn't return a promise

Comment: I am using `await` in the `const result = await Rating.aggregate` bit. I just forgot it the first time i posted it

Comment: Thanks...tried your answer. It got rid of the error, but I am getting an empty object back. Perhaps I am still doing something wrong...not calling getSum correctly. I am a C# .Net developer trying to learn Javascript / Node / React / Mongo / Express. C# .Net is so much easier...LOL

Comment: Does `console.log` in `getSum` function print the correct value?

Comment: Thank you. Your Edit was the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`then` only works on functions that return a `promise`. your function `getSum` is not returning anything, if `Rating.aggregate` function returns a promise, aka accepts a `then`, then you should return this aggregate, simply add `return` before calling it.

Now if `aggregate` doesn't return a promise, and I'm guessing so because you're passing a callback function to it, you might want to return a promise that resolves using `promise.resolve` in this callback body.

Comment: so are you saying that I basically have the return in the wrong place. Instead of returning count.total, I need to return Rating.aggregate...

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to absorb your answer...reading about promises on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise